# Using Python to cat a file over ssh to a remote bash script

Tags: python, bash, shlex

I'm using subprocess.popen with shlex to call a remote bash script using ssh.  This command works quite fine on bash itself.  But as soon as I try to translate it to python and shlex with subprocess.popen it errs out.

Remote bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp="";     
while read -r line;
do
    tmp="$tmp $line\n";
done;
echo $tmp;
```

**BASH CMD RESULT**(Invoking the remote bash script on the command line)

```
$> ssh x.x.x.x cat < /tmp/bef69a1d-e580-5780-8963-6a9b950e529f.txt " | /path/to/bash/script.sh;"
Bar\n
$>
```

Python code

```
import shlex
import subprocess

fn = '/tmp/bef69a1d-e580-5780-8963-6a9b950e529f.txt'
s = """                                                                    
ssh x.x.x.x cat < {localfile} '| /path/to/bash/script.sh;'
""".format(localfile=fn)

print s

lexer = shlex.shlex(s)                                                     
lexer.quotes = "'"                                                         
lexer.whitespace_split = True                                              
sbash = list(lexer)                                                        
print sbash                                                                

# print buildCmd                                                           
proc=subprocess.Popen(sbash,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE) 
out,err=proc.communicate()                                                 

print "Out: " + out                                                        
print "Err: " + err
```

**PYTHON SCRIPT RESULT**:

```
$> python rt.py

    ssh x.x.x.x cat < /tmp/bef69a1d-e580-5780-8963-6a9b950e529f.txt '| /path/to/bash/script.sh'
['ssh', 'x.x.x.x', 'cat', '<', '/tmp/bef69a1d-e580-5780-8963-6a9b950e529f.txt', "'| /path/to/bash/script.sh'"]
Out: 
Err: bash: /tmp/bef69a1d-e580-5780-8963-6a9b950e529f.txt: No such file or directory
$>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why does your python script have an extra `'<'` in the argument list which doesn't appear to be present in the bash script?  (Or am I reading this wrong?)

Comment: I missed that, typo.  I corrected it by placing the < in the bash commandline.

Comment: Is your `/tmp/bef69a1d-e580-5780-8963-6a9b950e529f.txt` file on the local or remote system? If it's local, I think I'd run your command differently, as `cat /tmp/bef69a1d-e580-5780-8963-6a9b950e529f.txt | ssh x.x.x.x /path/to/bash/script.sh` No need to run `cat` on the remote end. (I'm not sure if this will fix your Python issue though.)

Comment: @Blckknght UUOC (useless use of cat) in that one.  `ssh x.x.x.x /path/to/bash/script.sh < /tmp/bef...` is equivalent to the statement you wrote above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using shell redirection in the command, but there's no shell spawned when using subprocess.

Consider the following (very simple) program:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

Now if we run it like you're running `ssh` (assuming `foofile.txt` exists), we get:

```
python argcheck.py ssh cat < foofile.txt " | /path/to/bash/script.sh;"
['argcheck.py', 'ssh', 'cat', ' | /path/to/bash/script.sh;']
```

Notice that `< foofile.txt` never make it to python's commandline arguments.  That's because the bash parser intercepts the `<` and the file that comes after it and redirects the contents of that file to your program's stdin.  In other words, `ssh` is reading the file from stdin.  You want your file to be passed to `stdin` of `ssh` using python as well.

```
s = """                                                                    
ssh x.x.x.x cat '| /path/to/bash/script.sh;'
"""

#<snip>

proc=subprocess.Popen(sbash,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err=proc.communicate(open(fn).read())
```

will work presumably.

---

The following works for me:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

with open('foo.h') as f:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','mgilson@XXXXX','cat','| cat'],stdin=f,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
    out,err = p.communicate()
    print out
    print '#'*80
    print err
```

And the equivalent command in `bash`:

```
ssh mgilson@XXXXX cat < foo.h '| cat'
```

where `foo.h` is a file on my local machine.

Comment: Nice, never occurred to me using the communicate() as my stdin.  I do get a different error now

Out: 
Err: bash: cat | /path/to/bash/script.sh: No such file or directory

Seems like it's looking on my local machine, and failing.

Comment: @Chris -- I think you can directly pass the open file object to `stdin` in the `Popen` constructor as well.  That's probably a slightly more clean way of doing it.

Comment: Same thing.

Err: bash: cat | /path/to/bash/script.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: You rock, thank you, it works.  I really appreciate the work you put into this. :)